# How to pass arguments between Activities?

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I have a list item in one activity and a mapView in another activity. What I want to do is when i click on the first listItem it will show the current location and also spesific locations that I added there and after clicking the other listItems it will show Current location aswell but different spesific locations which will show under the same condition.

```
List<Hero> heroList;
ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_krakow);

heroList = new ArrayList<>();

heroList.add(new Hero(R.drawable.food,"Restaurant", "Justice League"));
heroList.add(new Hero(R.drawable.captainamerica,"Shopping Mall", "Avengers"));
heroList.add(new Hero(R.drawable.doctorstrange,"Hospital", "Avengers"));
heroList.add(new Hero(R.drawable.ironman,"Pharmacy", "Avengers"));
heroList.add(new Hero(R.drawable.joker,"Library", "Injustice League"));
heroList.add(new Hero(R.drawable.spi,"Second Hand", "Avengers"));

listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);

final MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this,R.layout.list_item,heroList);

listView.setAdapter(adapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent pos = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MapsActivity2.class);
            pos.putExtra("asdas",position);
            startActivity(pos);
        if (position==0){
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),MapsActivity2.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent,0);
        }
        if (position==1){
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),MapsActivity2.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent,1);
        }
        if (position==2){
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),MapsActivity2.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent,2);
        }
        if (position==3){
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),MapsActivity2.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent,3);
        }
        if (position==4){
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),MapsActivity2.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent,4);
        }
        if (position==5){
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),MapsActivity2.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent,5);
        }
    }
});






}

}
```

this is my listView

```
GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener{

private static final int MY_PERMISSION_CODE = 1000;
private GoogleMap mMap;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

private double latitude,longitude;
private Location mLastLocation;
private Marker mMarker;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

IGoogleAPIService mService;
private static final LatLng BaniaLuca = new LatLng(50.064146, 19.935940);
private static final LatLng Cocon = new LatLng(50.047654,19.947358);
private  Marker mBaniaLuca;
private Marker mCocon;
int asdas ;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps2);

    KrakowActivity asd = new KrakowActivity();
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if(extras != null){
        int asdas = extras.getInt("asdas");
    }

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    mService = Common.getGoogleAPIService();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    {
        checkLocationPermission();
    }
}

private boolean checkLocationPermission()
{
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{

                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

            },MY_PERMISSION_CODE);
        else
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{

                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

            },MY_PERMISSION_CODE);
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            buildGoogleApiClien();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
        else
        {
            buildGoogleApiClien();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }


}

private synchronized void buildGoogleApiClien()
{
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,mLocationRequest,this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLastLocation = location;
    if (mMarker != null)

        mMarker.remove();

    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
    mMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);



    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,13));
  // if (asdas == 0) {
       mBaniaLuca = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
               .position(BaniaLuca)
               .title("BaniaLuca"));
       mBaniaLuca.setTag(0);

       mCocon = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
               .position(Cocon)
               .title("Cocon"));
       mCocon.setTag(0);

 //  }else if (asdas == 1){

    /*   mBaniaLuca = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
               .position(BaniaLuca)
               .title("asdsad"));
       mBaniaLuca.setTag(0);

       mCocon = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
               .position(Cocon)
               .title("asdsadasdas"));
       mCocon.setTag(0);*/

      /* AlertDialog asd = new  AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
       asd.setMessage("asdasdsadas");
       asd.show(); */
 //  }else if (asdas == 2){


      /* AlertDialog asd = new  AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
       asd.setMessage("asdasdsadas");
       asd.show(); */
  // }


    if (mGoogleApiClient != null)
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,this);
}




}
```

and this is my MapView. Basically , I want to send (position) to another activity so it will understand that it clicked and change the map directions. Thanks in advance for any help and I am a beginner so forgive me for my mistakes.

Comment: what is the problem exactly? This is quite basic and there are **many** examples that go through this

Comment: Just google for that.

Comment: I know it is super basic. What i want is after clicking on  different listItems  they will show the same activity but with different conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use Extra part of the Intent. Instead of passing the list index, you can directly pass the coordinates you want. It supposes that the coordinates are part of the data linked to list item.

Comment: I understand it , Thank you so much sir!!